# Print Nashorn engine debug to a txt file

Tags: java, nashorn

I'm developing a functionality that lets the user execute custom scripts with Nashorn, one of the requirements is that the users can see a report(debug) of how the function was executed.

something like:

```
var a = context.valueA;
var b = context.valueB;
return a+b;
```

would print something like:

```
var a = 15;
var b = 10;
return 15+10; == 25
```

Does someone know a good way to do that? Or access the Nashorn debugger programmatically and get details of the execution?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ --- If you want to know how to debug Nashorn JavaScript, do a web search.

Comment: I don't want to simple debug Nashorn script, I want to know how to programmatically debug a Nashorn script.